# How can I create a radial UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-graphics

[image: This a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve]

I am trying to figure out how I can create a UIView with the shape of 'View 2' (see figure).

I have only been able to draw a single line bezier curve that fits the shape, but I cannot figure out how to make the view itself this shape...

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide some sample code?

Once I create this view. I will be looking for it to follow another bezier curve that is the same shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know logic for your shape but for example u want uiview to be like :[image]

Refere [this](http://pastebin.com/wc50RpHk) link.

Comment: Thanks! I think both you and @rmaddy pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

All `UIView` objects are rectangles. You can make them appear in any shape by making their background clear and drawing just the shape you want in the `drawRect:` method.

Comment: But if I add a gesture to the view won't the rectangle the shape is drawn inside of still move?

Comment: That's all up to how you implement the gesture and perform hit testing.